# Is there any way to make the AxAcroPDF Library work in 64 bit environment?

Tags: 64-bit, acrobat

We have created an application which we want to run in a 64 bit environment.

The issue we have is one of our forms uses a pdfviewer. The rest of the application works fine in a 64 bit environment. However, the only way the form with the pdf viewer (AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF) will work is if we make the whole application a 32 bit application.

The form with the pdfviewer will not work if the application is compiled as a 64 bit program.
 Are there any solutions to this issue?

Comment: You already found the solution: Set the platform target to x86 under Project -> Properties.

Comment: So basically there is no current way to make this run as a 64 bit application until Adobe upgrades their product?

Comment: You can try running the COM object out-of-process. But I don't think that's worth the effort (and btw it slows down calls into the COM object).

Comment: Could you in essence "answer my question" in the answer question area so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is not a solution until Adobe makes one.